# what is the correct way to deserialize this data in php (Laravel)?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

```
{"items":{
  "1":{
     "qty":1,
     "price":12.99,
     "item":{
        "id":1,
        "title":"Product 1 ",
        "delivery_time":"30",
        "description":"Product 1 Product 1 Product 1 Product 1",
        "created_at":"2021-06-21T11:43:00.000000Z",
        "updated_at":"2021-06-28T14:34:49.000000Z",
        "price":12.99
     }
  },
  "2":{
     "qty":1,
     "price":10,
     "item":{
        "id":2,
        "title":"random product",
        "delivery_time":"30",
        "description":"random product",
        "created_at":"2021-06-28T14:29:00.000000Z",
        "updated_at":"2021-06-28T14:34:35.000000Z",
        "price":10
     }
  }}}
```

I tried with foreach (items as item) {
item->qty (not working) and also item['qty'] (not working) tried with JSON encode and decode as well.

can anyone help what should be the correct approach?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the output of `var_dump(json_decode($json));` to it?

Comment: try `unserialize()` method.

Comment: That's invalid JSON. Make it valid, then `json_decode()` it.

Answer (score 3):

There are many types of serialized strings.

**1.Serialize (serialize() / unserialize())**

```
$array = array("Hello", "World", 100, 200);
$str = serialize($array);

# $str: a:4:{i:0;s:5:"Hello";i:1;s:5:"World";i:2;i:100;i:3;i:200;}
```

```
$str = 'a:4:{i:0;s:5:"Hello";i:1;s:5:"World";i:2;i:100;i:3;i:200;}';
$array = unserialize($str);

# $array: ["Hello", "World", 100, 200]
```

**2.JSON (json_encode() / json_decode())**

```
$array = array('Hello World', 1234, 5678);
$json_arr = json_encode($array);
$json_obj = json_encode((Object)$array); // for objects

# $json_arr: ["Hello World",1234,5678]
# $json_obj: {"0":"Hello World","1":1234,"2":5678}
```

```
$json = '{"0":"Hello World","1":1234,"2":5678}';
$object = json_decode($json);

# $object: 0 = 'Hello World' - 1 = 1234 - 2 = 5678
```

Answer (score 0):

You can casts this to Array php
before your json object you can add this (array)

Answer (score 0):

Note that there's "1", "2" and so on those are the keys to the iteration you have. print_r(item) that's what would most likely get. Use another foreach loop and you have access to qty, to get the things in item then u loop again. That is to get delivery_time for example. Not having my laptop now, would have help out